# Uber api ride request widget issue in android

Tags: android, uber-api

Bug relates to new ride request widget sdk introduced by uber on few days back

I am able to book cab via this widget, but when trying to call/message driver I am getting following error:

ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

```
String productId = bundle.getString(Constants.CAB_TYPE);

    RideRequestView rideRequestView = (RideRequestView) findViewById(R.id.uber_book);

    rideRequestView.setAccessToken(mAccessToken);

    rideRequestView.setRideRequestViewCallback(new RideRequestViewCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorReceived(RideRequestViewError error) {
            if(error !=null) {

                    Utils.showToast(UberBookViewActivity.this, error.name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            }
        }
    });

    if(bundle.containsKey(Constants.DESTINATION_ADDRESS)){
        RideParameters rideParamsWithDestination = new RideParameters.Builder()
                .setProductId(productId)
                .setPickupLocation(bundle.getDouble(Constants.LATITUDE, 0.0), bundle.getDouble(Constants.LONGITUDE, 0.0), bundle.getString(Constants.SOURCE_ADDRESS)
                        , bundle.getString(Constants.SOURCE_ADDRESS))
                .setDropoffLocation(bundle.getDouble(Constants.DEST_LATITUDE, 0.0), bundle.getDouble(Constants.DEST_LONGITUDE, 0.0), bundle.getString(Constants.DESTINATION_ADDRESS)
                        , bundle.getString(Constants.DESTINATION_ADDRESS))
                .build();
        rideRequestView.setRideParameters(rideParamsWithDestination);
    }else{
        RideParameters rideParams = new RideParameters.Builder()
                .setProductId(productId)
                .setPickupLocation(bundle.getDouble(Constants.LATITUDE, 0.0), bundle.getDouble(Constants.LONGITUDE, 0.0), bundle.getString(Constants.SOURCE_ADDRESS)
                        , bundle.getString(Constants.SOURCE_ADDRESS))
                .build();
        rideRequestView.setRideParameters(rideParams);
    }


    rideRequestView.load();
```

Attached is the screenshot of error [widget error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgv4J.png)

Comment: Looks like you found a bug in our SDK! We're working hard to get a fix out by later today or tomorrow. I will post an answer here once we've resolved the issue.

Thanks for catching this!

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK has been updated with a fix for this bug.

Answer (score 0):

[Release 0.3.1](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/releases/tag/v0.3.1) fixes [issue #15](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/issues/15#issuecomment-211616360) "RideRequestView correctly handles redirecting to call or message the driver" , which is exactly your problem.